# How can I compare numbers from a list only with the next number (neighbor)?

Tags: python, list, compare, list-comprehension

All I want to do is to compare the first number from a list with the second number from the same list, the second one with the third one, and so on.

input:

```
lst = [1,2,3,2,1]
```

output:

```
result = ["Lower", "Lower", "Higher", "Higher"]
```

(1 is lower than 2, 2 is lower than 3, 3 is higher than 2, 2 is higher than 1)

It's kinda ugly (a list comprehension would be great), but my approach for that would be:

```
lst = [1,2,3,2,1]
result = []
x = 0

try:
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[x] > lst[x+1]:
            result.append("Higher")
            #print("Higher")
        else:
            result.append("Lower")
            #print("Lower")
        x = x+1
except IndexError:
    print(result)
    print("Out of range")
```

Comment: Does it work?  If so, what is your question then? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: It works with my way, but the block it's a little too much for this simple operation, and I could't find how to do it as short as possible, like a list comprehension, which I received in the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is as a list comprehension

```
['Higher' if lst[i] > lst[i + 1] else 'Lower' for i in range(len(lst) - 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your strings `higher` and `lower` are basically proxies for boolean greater/less than, you can make this pretty clean with:

```
lst = [1,2,3,2,1]

vals = ['higher', 'lower']

[vals[m < n] for m, n in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
# ['lower', 'lower', 'higher', 'higher']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip()` to iterate over list:

```
lst = [1,2,3,2,1]

out = []
for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    out.append('Higher' if a > b else 'Lower')

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['Lower', 'Lower', 'Higher', 'Higher']
```

Comment: Much much cleaner than mine, thanks! Mitchel Paulin replied with a list comprehension, I will use that.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from turning this one to a list comprehension which I think comes out nice and clear. Should be fairly quick too-
['Higher' if a > b else 'Lower' for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:])]

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea with the `try`/`except` paradigm, but you are wrapping the entire loop in a try block. What you want instead is to ignore only the indices for which the IndexError occurs. So try this:

```
lst = [1,2,3,2,1]
result = []
x = 0

for i in range(len(lst)):
    try:
        if lst[x] > lst[x+1]:
            result.append("Higher")
            #print("Higher")
        else:
            result.append("Lower")
            #print("Lower")
        x = x+1
    except IndexError:
        print(result)
        print("Out of range")
```

---

Since you're comparing numbers in pairs, you know that your output list will have one fewer entry than the input list. Each index of the output list describes the relationship between the corresponding element in the input list and the next element in the input list.

```
lst = [1,2,3,2,1]
result = []
for i in range(len(lst)-1):
    a = lst[i]
    b = lst[i+1]

    if a<b:
        result.append("Lower")
    else:
        result.append("Higher")
```

Of course, you can do the whole thing as a one-liner

```
result = [("Lower", "Higher")[lst[i]>lst[i+1]] for i in range(len(lst)-1)]
```

Or the even terser:

```
result = [("Lower", "Higher")[a>b] for a,b in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a list comprehension, but perhaps more clear for non-pythonians:

```
lst = [1,2,3,2,1]
result = []
x = 0

for i in range(len(lst)-1):
  comp_result = "Higher" if lst[i] > lst[i+1] else "Lower"
  result.append(comp_result)

print(result)
```